# Cant access Windows Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I can't access Windows 10 although at boot screen there is an option. If I choose Windows there is a purple screen and freezes there. I did boot repair but still the same.

[image: My partitions]
[image: BootScreen]

I don't know what I messed up during installation

Will I need to format and reinstall Windows again?

fdisk output if it helps

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048 1518618623 1518616576 724,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3  *    1518618624 1778022399  259403776 123,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1778024446 1953523711  175499266  83,7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       1941108736 1953523711   12414976   5,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       1778024448 1941108432  163083985  77,8G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Once try to reinstall grub, open up your terminal, And then type this commands: `sudo  grub-install` and then enter your password and then run this command, after installing grub `sudo update-grub`. Now reboot.

Comment: Still the same. I ran Boot info Script and said that Grub2 is in /dev/sda so I reinstalled grub there. But nothing happened. I can access files from Ubuntu 16.04 but no access to windows 10. Should I install grub  somewhere else or something?

Answer (score 0):

i can't answer this specifically. but, i have seen a lot of questions about a dual boot with win 10.  i tried the same thing and same problem.  i could dual boot. but, had to go through hoops.  the windows boot loader didn't work. had to manually go in & select the partition to boot from.  HOWEVER, recently, i had a bad sector & reinstall ubuntu. (something else)  with automatic updating. that install keeps the data but reloads the system. i got back my system.  noticed that grub2 was updated. AND, now the ubuntu dual boot loader works.  my 2c.  suggest a reinstall with updating commponents. (it also got my flash viewer to upgrade & work)  using Ubuntu 16.0.4 LGT